Failed to notify dependency resolution listener. 'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions
After a couple years, I'm trying to revive my Android app, but after upgrading my SDK and Gradle versions, I'm hitting a brick wall.
What follows is the error message.
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'


build.gradle (app)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
compileSdk 31
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.paid"
    }
    pro {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.pro"
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'
/*packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
}*/
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.loopeer.library:cardstack:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.mutualmobile.android:cardstack:0.5.3'
implementation 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.badoualy:datepicker-timeline:c6dcd05737'
implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.3'
implementation 'com.github.Binary-Finery:EZDialog:2.0'
implementation 'com.michaelmuenzer.android:ScrollableNumberPicker:0.2.2'
implementation 'com.shuhart.bubblepagerindicator:bubblepagerindicator:1.1.2'
//for lifecycle and LiveData and ViewModel
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
implementation 'com.github.Binary-Finery:EZDialog:2.0'
def room_version = "2.2.5"
/*

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'
*/

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

// optional - Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
/*
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
*/

}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

build.gradle (Project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.30'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    //classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    //maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Thank you in advance.
I've tried different Gradle Versions pursuant to this, but nothing changed despite what the user said.

can you edit your question and post desired code and gradle files?

Could you please tell me you have found the solution or not? I am getting same error.

Change your classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2'

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
